# Trying to parse a wiki page with AngleSharp

Tags: anglesharp

I am trying to parse: [List of airlines (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airline_codes)

The page has a simple table:

```
<table class="wikitable sortable">
    <caption>Airline codes</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>IATA</th>
        <th>ICAO</th>
        <th>Airline</th>
        <th>Call sign</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Comments</th>
    </tr>

    etc...
```

I am aware that this could be parsed very easily with regex, but I never used AngleSharp and I want to figure it out.

I made a simple piece of code:

```
var parser = new HtmlParser();
var config = new Configuration();

var document = BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync(Url.Create("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airline_codes")).Result;

var aa = document.QuerySelectorAll("tr");
var bb = document.QuerySelectorAll("wikitable");
var cc = document.QuerySelectorAll("table");
```

The page gets loaded properly, but none of my queries are returning anything. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `Configuration` does not support document loading so you get an empty document. Use `WithDefaultLoader` to load a config that does.

So change

```
var config = new Configuration();
```

to

```
var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();
```

Comment: That explains a lot :) I added the loader (can't find any doc for this btw) but I still don't get anything from that document. document.QuerySelectorAll("wikitable").Select(_ => true) should select the whole table, no?

Comment: @Thomas The `wikitable` that you're looking for is a css class, not a tag. So it should be `.wikitable` with the dot in the front to denote a class. Like  `document.QuerySelectorAll(".wikitable")`

Comment: so if I understand, I grab ".wikitable" to have the class, then I need to find all the 'tr that belong to that class? how can I search on a type ('tr'). Also, is there any place with a full documentation? the examples on the wiki are very terse

Comment: @Thomas that's correct. You can do it in one query `(".wikitable tr")`. This would find all `tr` in `.wikitable`. The syntax for query selectors is basically the [CSS Selector syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors).

Comment: ok, I'm starting to get it! is there a way to do a select to grab all the columns as a list? something like select(_ = new { C1 = _.(something that gets column 1), C2 = _.(...) }) ?

Comment: looks like this can work: var aa = document.QuerySelectorAll(".wikitable tr").Select(_ => _.TextContent).Split('\n'); Thanks for the help!